# nginx.ingress annotations not working for basic authentication in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup basic authentication on Kubernetes but the IP I obtain after setting up authentication using the nginx.ingress annotations  is still publicly accessible. Below is the link I referred to in setting this up-

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/08/14/using-kubernetes-ingress-authentication.html

After following the process in the link, I should be prompted to enter the username and password when I hit that IP but instead I'm able to access it without any authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/45bdc249bc27bdf427498b42859e1a98d634bff0/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/auth/README.md) which shows how to add authentication specific to GKE.

You can [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) an nginx ingress controller in your GKE cluster. Please make sure to  annotate your ingress to avoid the GLBC claiming the ingress as specified in this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx#running-multiple-ingress-controllers). Then you can expose the nginx controller directly, or create a glbc ingress to redirect traffic to the nginx ingress as specified in this [link](https://gist.github.com/bprashanth/8975c55789d201c7d8a7575f5c2a4565).